# "Unknown source" when debugging with VSCode a binary generated from a C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug some C++ code. When running the debugger on the targeted file, the majority of the stack frames are greyed, showing a "Unknown source". What's the cause of this?
The launch.json I am using is:

```js
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "My debug session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build_tests/${input:p_1}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
      "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "p_1",
      "description": "What Unit Tests do you want to run?",
      "options": [
        "test/unit_tests/my_test"
      ],
      "default": "test/unit_tests/my_test",
      "type": "pickString"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you build the code?